# where is ca certs file in ldap3?

Tags: python, active-directory, domaincontroller, ldap3, cacerts

I am using ldap3 and want to create a conncetion over SSL. I have seen that in order to so I must create a Tls object with the arugment "ca_certs_file". My problem is, I cannot understand from where can I retrieve such a file.

```
from ldap3 import Server, Connection, NTLM, Tls
import ssl
tls=Tls(validate=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED, ca_certs_file=<FILE_PATH>)
server = Server("DONAIN.com", use_ssl=True, tls=tls)
conn = Connection(server, user="DOMAIN\\admin", password="PASSWORD", authentication=NTLM)
conn.bind()
```

For example in the above code, where do I find <FILE_PATH>?

Where is it configured?

(The client machine is a Windows 10 and the server is a domain controller Windows Server 2019).

Comment: To connect to a specific site you need the cert of the CA that issued the site cert. A CA cert is just a self-signed cert that is authorized to sign other certs. Browsers include a bundle of trusted CA certs.

Comment: And how do I find the cert of the CA that issued the site cert?

Answer (score -2):

You have to add this certificate manually on your server first.
Please look at [Enable LDAP over SSL with a third-party certification authority](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/identity/enable-ldap-over-ssl-3rd-certification-authority). This article explains all needed steps to do this.
The mentioned `ca_certs_file` is the public ROOT CA of your server, which might be a self signed one.

Comment: Nobodyman, a link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)